# Core Animation - Sheet-like Window Sliding

Tags: cocoa, core-animation, nsview

How difficult would it be to use core animation to make an NSView slide in an out of view like a sheet? Generally speaking, what would be involved in accomplishing this? I've been reading through the CA documentation, but it's been hard for me to pinpoint which parts are relevant to what I want to do since I have no experience with the framework.

Any tips at all would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're talking of a NSView, you're probably using Cocoa's animation support, not CA directly. In this case, you just need to set the view's frame through the view's animator object:

```
[theView setFrame:offscreenFrame];
[[theView animator] setFrame:finalFrame];
```

Unfortunately, Cocoa view animation interacts badly with the more advanced features of CA, like setting an easing. You might have more luck using NSViewAnimation instead, which is not Core Animation-backed and allows for a little more flexibility.

Comment: Interesting. I'll look into this. Thanks.