# Using pushViewController after presentModalViewController

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

In my app I have BaseViewController (NavigationController) as the root controller. I normally use the following code to navigate:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:childController animated:YES];
```

But on one of the actions I want the next view to animate buttom to top, so I use:

```
[self presentModalViewController:childController animated:YES];
```

Everything works so far. In the modal view I then want to push another controller, but this doesn't seem to work. I have tried the following:

```
// self.navigationController is null, so this doesn't work
[self.navigationController pushViewController:childController animated:YES];

// self.parentViewController is the BaseViewController and not null, but this 
// won't work either. This also generates a warning "UIViewController' may not 
// respond to '-pushViewController:animated:"
[self.parentViewController pushViewController:childController animated:YES];
```

In both cases nothing happens. Is pushViewController disabled while a modal view is still showing? If so, is there another way I can:

1. Animate next controller from bottom to top
2. Animate the next controller from left to right, with a back button as usual. The back button should take you back to the previous (modal) view.

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you presentModelViewController then you need to dismiss it before you can call the navigation controller's methods, otherwise you have to put this view controller into the navigation stack in order to put another view controller on top of it.

Comment: Based on your answer, I made a solution that works. Instead of presenting the childcontroller modal directly, I create another instance of BaseViewController and add this one modally. The pushViewController then works as expected, since the modal view now contains a navigationcontroller:

ChildController *childController = [[ChildController alloc] init];
BaseTrackingViewController *baseController = [[BaseTrackingViewController alloc] initWithRootViewController:childController];
[self presentModalViewController:baseController animated:YES];

Answer (score 1):

Use the following lines of code to present childController, then navigationcontroller will not be null so it will work as u want.

```
UINavigationController * childNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:childController];
childNavigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;//if u want to show navigation bar then remove this line
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:coinsNavigationController animated:YES];
```

After presentModelViewController you can present or push any other view controller within presented view controller.

```
// self.navigationController in this case will never be null. so following line will work perfectly inside presented child View controller (childController)
[self.navigationController pushViewController:childController animated:YES];
```

Here is the desired output:

1. childController will be presented via animation bottom to top over BaseViewController
2. An other instance of child controller will be pushed via animation left to right over childController.

Hope this will be useful and easy solution.

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful: [Core Animation - Sheet-like Window Sliding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574680/core-animation-sheet-like-window-sliding)

If you use that in conjunction with `[self.navigationController pushViewController:childController animated:NO];` to disable the native animation, it may produce the effect you're looking for.

Don't forget to reverse the operation when popping childController off the nav stack.

Answer (score 0):

Using the following method, you first present the childViewController modally with animated:YES, then dismiss it without any animation and then push it on the view controller without animation. You will need to create your own navigation bar for this view and will need to hide the navigation bar of the navigation controller.

```
        [self presentModalViewController:childController animated:YES];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
            sleep(1);

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
                [self.navigationController pushViewController:childController animated:NO];
            });
        });
```

In the childController when cancel button clicked:

```
if (self.navigationController != nil) {
    if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didDissmissSearchViewController)]) {
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
        [delegate didDissmissChildViewController];
    }
    else {
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    }
}
```

and in the delegate:

`- (void)didDissmissSearchViewController
{
    [self presentModalViewController:childController animated:NO];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}`